# "Uncaught TypeError" on page refresh OR new page only...?

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror, page-refresh, pageload

The following code outline works PERFECTLY when I navigate to an HTML/EJS page, it successfully populates some  tags (prefixed with "group_") with images passed to the document:

external.js:

```
addEventListener("load", seeds);

function seeds() {

//...stuff here to define variables and run a loop to populate the tags 

  //**ADD THE PHOTO...

  _item = document.createElement("img"); 
  _item.setAttribute("id", "seed_" + _str);
  _item.setAttribute("src", "/galleries/pix/" + _cat + "/" + _str);
  _item.setAttribute("alt", "picture of " + _str);
  _item.setAttribute("max-width", '100%');
  document.getElementById("group_" + _tally).appendChild(_item);  //Uncaught TypeError (appendChild) here...ONLY on page 'refresh' or load page in a new tab...works fine the 'first' page load only...

  //**

//...more stuff that does not run after the "Uncaught TypeError" on 'reloads'

}
```

My issue is that if I do a page 'refresh', OR navigate to load the page again in a new tab...I receive an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null" error and the script fails at that point.  Another odd thing is that the images are created as they should, however the remainder of the script stops functionality.

It seems that the event listener for "load" runs fine the first time, however on each subsequent attempt to load the page throws the error.  Is there perhaps some other event listener that is required for subsequent page loads?  I do not believe that should be the case.

Any advice on what the problem may be is greatly appreciated.  I thank you in advance.

Comment: The error is pretty straightforward: `document.getElementById("group_" + _tally)` returns null because no matching element exists (yet). Now you need to find out why.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  The "group_" + tally does exist.  If it did not then why does the code work flawlessly on the initial execution?  The error only occurs on subsequent runs.

Comment: Will it creat new element with the same id ```"seed_" + _str```.Would the id be duplicated ?

Comment: Just do some basic debugging then: `const el = document.getElementById("group_" + _tally);` then `console.log("appending to", el);`. What does it say?

Comment: OK I have it solved, the array holding the image names was being improperly incremented when it should not have been.  Thank you to all for the replies.